# postmodifying phrase/under the leadership of

Tags: phrases, ambiguity

Are these sentences correct:

1. Such activities found favor with the social democrats under the leadership of Schmidt.
2. Such activities found favor with the social democrats **,** under the leadership of  Schmidt.
3. Such activities found favor with social democrats under the leadership of Schmidt.
4. Such activities found favor with social democrats **,** under the leadership of  Schmidt.

Which of the above mean:

> a. Such activities found favor with **those of the social democrats who were under the leadership of Schmidt.**

and which mean:

> b. Such activities found favor with the social democrats, **who were all under the leadership of Schmidt.**

I am not sure the ones with the commas work at all. Maybe the phrase at the end is dangling.

Without the comma, the phrase seems restrictive, so the sentences 1 and 3 would normally correspond to *a*, but maybe one could see the noun phrase as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

None of the sentences clearly states what you want to say.  They all convey the sense that the social democrats found the activities desirable AND Schmidt leads the social democrats

Try something like *Such activities found favor with the Schmidt wing of the social democrats*.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1 and 3 would have the same meaning as A. Sentence 2 and 4 are not grammatically viable. Ideally the last clause should make sense as a sentence on it's own. For example, in this instance you could make sentence 2+4 viable by adding "who were" just as in meaning B. I hope this helps.

Comment: Even with that modification, it's not clear that the sentence is only referring to a subset of the social democrats, rather than describing the relationship between the party and Schmidt.

Comment: It seems to me that sentences 1 and 3 would much more likely be interpreted as *" ... found favor with the social democrats **while** they were under the leadership of Schmidt."* It's a restrictive relative clause, but it could be restricting to a time period, and not to a faction of the social democrats.

Answer (score -1):

While I would interpret (1) and (3) as restrictive relative clauses, I would interpret them as meaning

> ... found favor with all of the social democrats **while** they were under the leadership of Schmidt,

and not

> ... found favor with those social democrats **who** were under the leadership of Schmidt.

So the relative clause restricts to a time period rather than to a faction of the social democrats. This has nearly the same meaning as your sentence (b). Until your question, I didn't realize that restrictive relative clauses could be ambiguous in this way.